# Detect when an <ng-include src="..."> loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, deferred-rendering

I'm using an `<ng-include>` inside of a modal to load different contents conditionally based on some options.

The contents are selected when the modal is launched in one mode (heh) or another, or when the user changes a drop down.

In any of these cases, a section in my template like this loads in the right modal contents:

```
<!-- Load in the correct modal contents -->
<ng-include src="'modals/contents-'+ form.type +'.html'"></ng-include>
```

It then loads `modals/contents-addressForm.html` or whatever the case may be.

The trick is, the different forms are different sizes. When they load, the modal needs to reposition itself.

I have tried `$watch` on the `form.type` variable. This detects both changes and initial value on modal launch, but the reposition happens too soon because the `ng-include` hasn't yet loaded in content. I have tried a defer but this isn't always long enough. I could try a timeout of arbitrary length but this seems... arbitrary.

Any way to know when any ng-include loads? When the next ng-include loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude#$includeContentRequested), you should be able to listen to a scope event called `$includeContentLoaded` to tell this.

```
$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function () {
    // it has loaded!
});
```

Comment: Yay that rocks! It says the target is "the current ngInclude scope". Do these event bubble up the scope tree or up the DOM tree? oo... or neither. I can find out later, but I'm checking out for this evening. Thanks @GregL!

Comment: They bubble up the scope tree. The actual line in Angular's source is: `currentScope.$emit('$includeContentLoaded');`. And we know `$emit()` sends events UP the scope chain (`$broadcast()` sends them from the target scope DOWN). The "target scope" (the original scope the event was emitted/broadcast on) is accessible by accessing the `targetScope` property of the `$event` object that gets passed as the first argument to scope event handler functions.

Comment: Update: Listening at the modal parent scope to the `$includeContentLoaded` event works great. I have in some cases many content areas, so I debounce the event handler and reposition the modal whenever any of the content regions load in. I can also get `arguments[0].targetScope`, but I cannot figure out the original triggering ng-include src path from this, can I?

Comment: If you use multiple includes it will trigger many times, so be careful with it. @Miraage answer is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).

> onload (optional) Expression to evaluate when a new partial is loaded.

```
<!-- Load in the correct modal contents -->
<ng-include src="'modals/contents-'+ form.type +'.html'"
            onload="myFunction()"></ng-include>
```